# wanted to improve python socket processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

The requirement is to receive *all* traffic from port1(p1p1) and then encapsulate those packets to udp port xxx and send it out on port2 on 5 different source ips.

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
import time
import re
import random
from collections import namedtuple


def get_socket_connection():
    global sw_list
    udp_port = int('xxx')

    for i in range(0, 5):
        IP = '10.10.1.%d'%(1+i)
        try:
            #socket connections to send out the encapsulated traffic
            globals()[f"send_sock_{i}"] = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            globals()[f"send_sock_{i}"].bind((IP, 0))
        except socket.error as msg:
            print('Socket could not be created for IP %s. Error Code : %s ' %(IP, str(msg)))
            sys.exit()

    try:
        #socket connection to receive raw/native traffic
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket could not be created to read the traffic. Error Code : %s ' %(str(msg)))
        sys.exit()

    # receive a packet
    while True:
        packet = s.recvfrom(65565)

        #receive traffic ONLY from port p1p1 otherwise DO NOT PROCESS

        if packet[1][0] != 'p1p1':
            continue

        packet = packet[0]
        num = random.randint(0, 4)
        globals()[f"send_sock_{num}"].sendto(header_get(sw_list[num].port, sw_list[num].dpid, packet), (str('1.1.1.1'), int(udp_port)) )

def mac_to_int(mac):
    res = re.match('^((?:(?:[0-9a-f]{2}):){5}[0-9a-f]{2})$', mac.lower())
    if res is None:
        raise ValueError('invalid mac address')
    #print(int(res.group(0).replace(':', ''), 16))
    return int(res.group(0).replace(':', ''), 16)

def header_get(port, dpid, data_packet):
    global iteration
    pkt=struct.pack("!2I2Q", 2, port, dpid, round(time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_REALTIME)))
    iteration += 1
    print(iteration)
    return (pkt+data_packet)

def main():

    global proto_dic, iteration, sw_list

    iteration = int(0)
    sw = namedtuple("sw", ["num", "sw_name", "dpid", "port"])
    sw_list = []
    count = int(0)

    sw_list.append(sw(count+1, "s1", mac_to_int('3c:2c:30:5c:61:80'), int(1)))
    sw_list.append(sw(count+2, "s2", mac_to_int('98:5d:82:c1:a0:80'), int(1)))
    sw_list.append(sw(count+3, "s3", mac_to_int('20:04:0f:2c:cf:42'), int(1)))
    sw_list.append(sw(count+4, "s4", mac_to_int('e4:f0:04:32:94:1a'), int(1)))
    sw_list.append(sw(count+5, "s5", mac_to_int('3c:2c:99:69:2e:2c'), int(1)))
    sw_list.append(sw(count+6, "s5", mac_to_int('3c:2c:99:69:2e:2c'), int(2)))

    get_socket_connection()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As such the above code is working fine however, it is unable to process more than 20k pps guaranteed rate. I'm looking for atleast 75K guaranteed rate so I would like to know what optimizations can to be done to get such performances? This server has 4 CPU core and 16G ram.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry if this is critical, and with with these requirements you are better hiring a consulting person to upgrade/guarrantee that rather than a q/a site. 
That said, it looks like this code is single-threaded, single-process, non-async, so there is a lot of space for improvement. (after which you can move to cython/pypy/mypyc for some extra juice)

Comment: It won't help speed but for readability use a `list` for `send_sock` instead of the awful `globals()[f'send_sock_num}']` so you can use `send_sock[num]`.

Comment: If it works, you could try to post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), to get an extensive review. For my penny, compiling a regex *before* a loop is dramatically faster than (automatically) compiling it inside the loop.